# "Burger" lanes: What are they, where are they found, and what do they look like?

Tags: civil-engineering, traffic-intersections

*What* and *where* are they, and what do they *look like*?

Do all transportations with roundabouts use them in some form?

This is different from [What's the purpose of a 'burger' lane in a roundabout?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/11611/36705), which is very specific to *why*. This is an open floor to describe where and what they are, since not all transportation systems will have these.

Comment: I think it was answered nicely with an example photo. Why ask again?

Comment: if pictures do not suffice, i can try words. a burg is apparently a town.  a burg-er could be someone going to town.  more throughput directly to town, going against the roundabout... as for roundabout, this could be an example...

Comment: the comment after the answer has a picture

Comment: it may be called burger lane because it passes through the circular center of the roundabout ... the roundabout center is usually raised and landscaped, and is somewhat like a giant hamburger

Comment: If you are "unfamiliar with roundabouts" then you obviously lack familiarity with them…

Comment: No, the question as stated was too narrow: [What's the purpose of a 'burger' lane in a roundabout?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11611/whats-the-purpose-of-a-burger-lane-in-a-roundabout) asks "why", which made the answers so narrow I'd have to rewrite the question. This clearly goes on to establish "what" and "where" they are. Also, that original issue's question has a broken image.  I also welcome other ideas to add to clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your question is how they look like then:

[image]

**figure: source [hulldailymail](https://www.hulldailymail.co.uk/news/hull-east-yorkshire-news/hulls-new-a63-hamburger-roundabout-3044314)**

or

[image]

**figure: source [openstreet wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Throughabout)**

They are also known as ["through roundabouts"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roundabout#Through_roundabout)

As to their name I suppose  that the names comes from the fact that it looks like a hamburger. I.e. the two buns are the green islands and the two lanes of the road are the cheese and bacon slices.